# Android: How to get real path from Uri for Any file

Tags: android, kotlin

I want the real path from uri of a file type Any, I have the code for an image file but it does not work for what I want.

My file I want is a CSV file:

```
private fun getRealPathFromURI(contentURI: Uri, context: Context): String {
            val result: String
            val cursor = context.contentResolver.query(contentURI, null, null, null, null)
            if (cursor == null) { // Source is Dropbox or other similar local file path
                result = contentURI.path
            } else {
                cursor.moveToFirst()
                val idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA)
                result = cursor.getString(idx)
                cursor.close()
            }
            return result
        }
```

**EDIT:**
RESOLVED:

```
//On recupere le chemin du fichier ou manuellement ou par un picker
        val path = data.data

        //On ouvre le fichier du chemin
        val `is` = context.contentResolver.openInputStream(path)

        //Puis on le lis
        val reader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(`is`))
```

Comment: no, you dont need a path, you need an `InputStream` for data reading

Answer (score 0):

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
    String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(context, contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    Cursor cursor = loader.loadInBackground();
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String result = cursor.getString(column_index);
    cursor.close();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: It would be worth putting a few words of explanation in your answer - this might help others understand how you've solved the original poster's question. Thanks.